# Make UIImageView circle without dividing it with it's own height

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, rounding, geometry

Is there any other way to make image to be circle in swift other than this method:

```
 championImageView.clipsToBounds = true
 championImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
 championImageView.layer.cornerRadius = (championImageView.frame.size.width)/2
```

This wouldn't work for me because I use constraints for the image so the height and width is not the actual value. I also tried to put

```
layoutIfNeeded()
```

to no avail. And I also cannot set it on viewdidAppear() because the imageView lives inside an xib for CollectionViewCell.

Comment: Change it in the CollectionViewCell?

Comment: make maskToBounds false i.e. `championImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false`

Comment: “Is there any other way to make image to be circle in swift other than this method” Yes there is. In fact, that is the worst way to do it.

Comment: @matt I don't think, Create custom imageview class and override `draw` method. How it can be worst?

Comment: Instead of calling layoutIFNeeded(), add your code in this method layoutsubviews

Comment: there is no way (atleast as simple as it is) mathematically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. I set the layoutIfNeeded() on only the imageView, ignoring the fact that the image was inside a stackView. So I put it on the entire cell:

```
myCell.championImageView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

to

```
myCell.layoutIfNeeded()
```